# Quantopian data history showing only minute prices

Tags: python

I cant figure out why Im only getting minute data in the console rather than daily data, no matter what i state in the code, whether I write `frequency = '1d'` or `frequency = '1m'`, the result is always in minutes

```
def initialize(context):
    # AAPL, MSFT, and SPY
    context.securities = [sid(24), sid(5061), sid(8554)]

def handle_data(context, data):
    prices = data.history(context.securities, "price", bar_count = 10, frequency = "1d")
    pct_change = (prices.ix[-1] - prices.ix[0]) / prices.ix[0]
    log.info(pct_change)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `data.history()` returns a panel with the most recent 10 days of data.  That panel *includes today*.  You're making the call every minute, so the prices for the 9 past days in the panel are fixed, but the price for today is updating every minute.

I think you'll find the Getting Started tutorial's [Lesson 6](https://www.quantopian.com/tutorials/getting-started#lesson6) to be very informative.  It's common to drop today's price to avoid the situation you're in right now.

```
prices = data.history(context.securities, "price", bar_count = 11, frequency = "1d")
pct_change = (prices.ix[-2] - prices.ix[0]) / prices.ix[0]
```